# How to know if my graphic card is working well in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: drivers, gnome

---

I have x555dg laptop with : 
- AMD A10 8700P
- Radeon R5 ( Integrated ) and R6 M340DX 2 GB VRAM ( Dedicated ) [ actually i have no idea which one that is working in my ubuntu ]

I have checked " Additional Drivers " but i can't find any amd radeon drivers.
How can i know if my vga is installed correctly or not?

Thanks for the answers :)

Comment: There is nothing to install. So it is OK.

Answer (score 1):

There are no proprietary AMD drivers for Ubuntu 16.04 (yet).
AMD is improving support for the open source Radeon and AMDGPU drivers (one or the other will be installed and in use depending on your card).
You won't find any additional drivers in that section due to what I explained above.